# Can't interact with a window (HWND) cpp

Tags: c++, winapi, minimize, hwnd

I want to be able to minimize/maximize a window of a process that I create with `ShellExecuteEx()`.

First, I find the process ID and its `HWND` (I made sure it was the good `HWND` with Spy++).

Next, I try to minimize with `ShowWindow(hwnd)` or with `ShowWindow(GetForegroundWindow(), SW_MINIMIZE)`.

But it doesn't work. I made sure the process was elevated (administrator rights).  This seems to work with any other windows, such as the one for Notepad, RocketLeague, or whatever.  But this one window doesn't react.  When I call `SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)` I can see it flashing in the Taskbar, so I'm sure it is the right `HWND` for my application to use.

Any idea of what the issue might be?

Comment: ***Any idea of what the issue might be?***  The program can detect this and do what it wants.

Comment: Try `WM_SYSCOMMAND` with `SC_MINIMIZE` or `SC_MAXIMIZE`

Comment: It works! Thanks Paul Sanders!

SendMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0);

Comment: @Paul Sanders Put it as answer. This is how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Use SPY++ to find className and windowName, then you can:

```
HWND hWnd = ::FindWindow(className, windowName);
::ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

SendMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0);

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the foreground window might not be the one you expect. You can never be 100% sure the newly created window will actually be the foreground window. The end user might get surprised if a random window is suddenly maximized. Also, what if you perform this action a few milliseconds before the new process has started up completely? A more robust solution would be to use `CreateProcess` and then find a window with a known class name that is associated with the PID returned by `CreateProcess`. You might even use `WaitForInputIdle` here, I guess.